# How to suppress Large Query message in R?

Tags: r, suppressmessage

I use pxweb to query data from Swedish statistics.

But I have problem to hide the large query problem.

[image]

I have tried to hide it with echo, message, warning = FALSE

but nothing works.

Wondering how I can hide this message.

Comment: Did you try `suppressMessages`? What about `sink`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of the function [here](https://github.com/rOpenGov/pxweb/blob/master/R/pxweb_get.R#L123) I can see that the authors decided to use `cat` to enlighten you with the message. This can be circumvented in a few ways, like flushing it into the void using `capture.output`. However, for your use case, try setting `pxweb_get(..., verbose = FALSE)` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank u!!!! it has been solved!